# removing timer is not working

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do I correctly remove/stop a timer in actionscript?

I do it like in this piece of code but timer has been set to fire frame1SoundTimerHandler in 200 seconds later :

```
            playingScreenFramesObj.myTimer2.stop(); 
            playingScreenFramesObj.myTimer2.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, frame1SoundTimerHandler);
            playingScreenFramesObj.myTimer2 = null;
```

It seems that despite stopping/removing the timer with the code above the handler will run in 200 seconds.

Where is the mistake I make?

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only have to call timer.stop(). As a failsafe you could always check timer.running from inside the event handler.

Comment: Your solution looks nice for debugging but how do I access running parameter from inside event handler?

Comment: You should be able access the timer as event.target, you may need to cast it to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work. Are you positive you are calling stop on the correct timer? For example, could you accidentally be using timer1 and stopping timer2?