# How do I find out in the event handler if the timer is running?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do I access timer.running from inside event handler?

Chris

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077321/removing-timer-is-not-working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `event.currentTarget` is the timer instance itself you can cast it back to timer

```
private function myTimerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{
   var tmr:Timer = event.currentTarget as Timer;
}
```